# Reading a delimited text file in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a txt file with many mysql inserts (1.5 million).
I need to read this file with python and divide this file at each ';' for each query and run the query with python. How can I divide this file at each ';'? And run the query with python?
Until now my code is:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="da66ro",
                     db="test")

f = open('E:/estudos/projetos/tricae/tests_python.txt')
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the file into `mysql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the file:

```
with open('youfilename.sql', 'r') as f:
    fileAsString = f.read().replace("\n", "")

sqlStatements = fileAsString.split(";")
```

Then to run the query:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
for statement in sqlStatements:
    try:
        cursor.execute(statement)
        db.commit()
    except:     
        db.rollback()
```

But of course you must realize this is a terrible idea. What happens when you have a quoted ";" character in a string you are inserting? You'll have to be a bit more clever than what you posed as a question - in general it's a terrible idea to assume anything about any data you are inserting into a database.

Or even worse than a broken query: what about malicious code? SQL injection? Never trust input you haven't sanitized.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Althought my text file is huge, it's just addresses. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, first you need read the file and split it by ";", which is done with `split()` function. Then you can loop or select which queries to execute (or just execute the whole file without splitting). You can find numerous examples on each of these and I'm sure it will be easy enough to combine them in what you need.

> I need to [read this file with python](https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=read+this+file+with+python&oq=read+this+file+with+python&gs_l=hp.12..0i22i30l4.68598.68598.4.69473.1.1.0.0.0.0.206.206.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.FuPmEQOA8W8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.dGI&fp=211d78910c70c5a4&biw=1920&bih=979) and [divide this file at
>   each ';'](https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=WJU7GHKUEaMQmrb7P-H80w&pq=divide%20this%20file%20at%20each%20%27;%27&cp=7&gs_id=6q&xhr=t&q=python+divide+this+file+at+each+%27;%27&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=python+divide+this+file+at+each+%27;%27&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.dGI&fp=211d78910c70c5a4&biw=1920&bih=979) for each query and [run the query with python](https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=run+the+query+with+python&oq=run+the+query+with+python&gs_l=hp.12..35i39.25136.25136.10.25691.1.1.0.0.0.0.191.191.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.xxuV1ecxCsY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.dGI&fp=211d78910c70c5a4&biw=1920&bih=979).

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python.. Here is the work around

```
import io

myfile = open('69_ptc_group_mappingfile_mysql.sql')

data = (myfile.read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8")).lower()

query_list=[]

if 'delimiter' not in data:

query_list = (data.strip()).split(";")

else:

tempv =  (data.rstrip()).split('delimiter')
for i in tempV:
    if (i.strip()).startswith("//"):
        i = i.rstrip().split("//")
        for a in i:
            if len(a)!=0:
                query_list.append(a.strip())
    else:
        corr = ((i.rstrip()).split(";"))
        for i in corr:
            if len(i.rstrip())!=0:
                query_list.append(i.rstrip())
```

print query_list

for j in query_list: cursor.execute(j)